# Joints: How to include icomoon icon into rappid's custom shape

Tags: svg, jointjs, rappid, icomoon

I'm using the **Rappid** framework for HTML diagramming tooling. I've made custom shapes using `dia.Element` from rappid's namespace using the below example. Anyhow, images are working fine using SVG, but I want to use ***icomoon/font-awesome*** icon instead.

```
export const Element = dia.Element.define(
    "custom.Element",
    {
        size: {height: 165, width: 140},
        attrs: {
            body: {
                refWidth: "100%",
                refHeight: "100%",
                fill: "transparent",
            },
            logoWrapper: {
                refX2: 25,
                refY2: 40,
            },
            logoContainer: {
                height: 75,
                width: 90,
                fill: "#fff",
                stroke: "#9C9C9C",
                rx: 6,
                ry: 6,
            },
            appLogo: {
                width: 48,
                height: 48,
                refX: 21,
                refY: 14,
                fontFamily: "icomoon",
                content: `\eb65`,
                text: `\eb65`,
            },
            ...otherProps,
        } as Record<string, SVGAttributes>,
    },
    {
        markup: [
            {
                tagName: "rect",
                selector: "body",
            },
            {
                tagName: "g",
                selector: "logoWrapper",
                children: [
                    {
                        tagName: "rect",
                        selector: "logoContainer",
                    },
                    {
                        tagName: "text",
                        selector: "appLogo",
                    },
                    ...otherMarkup,
                ],
            },
        ] as dia.MarkupJSON,
    }
);
```

Here I've used the `attr` on custom element on appLogo:

```
appLogo: {
  width: 48,
  height: 48,
  refX: 21,
  refY: 14,
  // here I've used the font-family or content/text
  // to fiddle with it, but no luck
  fontFamily: "icomoon",
  content: `\eb65`,
  text: `\eb65`,
}
```

And the markup is like this:

```
{
  tagName: "text",
  selector: "appLogo",
},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by using the correct font code. Needed to append `\u` to the `text` string. And the `content` prop is no longer required.

```
{
  text: '\ueb65'
}
```